# Como fazer um teste com JUnit num C R U D?

Tags: java, mysql, testes, crud

Gostaria de saber qual a condição usar dentro do teste.

Tenho a classe Cliente

```
package br.myhome.web.model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Cliente {

private int id;
private String nome;
private String telefone;
private String email;

public Cliente() {}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}
public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Cliente [id=" + id + ", nome=" + nome + ", telefone=" + telefone + ", email=" + email + "]";
}

// C R U D

public void cadastrar(Connection conn) {
    String sqlInserir = 
            "INSERT INTO CLIENTE (nome, telefone, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    try {
        stm = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInserir);
        stm.setString(1, getNome());
        stm.setString(2, getTelefone());
        stm.setString(3, getEmail());
        stm.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1.getStackTrace());
        }
    } finally {
        if (stm!=null) {
            try {
                stm.close();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                System.out.println(e1.getStackTrace());

            } 
        }
    }
}

public void alterar (Connection conn) {
    String sqlAlterar = 
            "UPDATE CLIENTE  SET nome = ?, telefone = ?, email = ? WHERE ID = ?";
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    try {
        stm = conn.prepareStatement(sqlAlterar);
        stm.setString(1, getNome());
        stm.setString(2, getTelefone());
        stm.setString(3, getEmail());
        stm.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } try {
        conn.rollback();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.println(e1.getStackTrace());

    } finally {
        if (stm != null) {
            try {
                stm.close();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                System.out.println(e1.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
    }
}

public void excluir(Connection conn) {
    String sqlExcluir = 
            "DELETE FROM CLIENTE WHERE ID = ?";
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    try {
        stm = conn.prepareStatement(sqlExcluir);
        stm.setInt(1, getId());
        stm.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1.getStackTrace());
        } 
    }   finally {
        if (stm!= null) {
            try {
                stm.close();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                System.out.println(e1.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
    }
}

public void carregar (Connection conn) {
    String sqlCarregar = 
            "SELECT id, nome, telefone, email WHERE ID = ?";
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        stm = conn.prepareStatement(sqlCarregar);
        stm.setInt(1, getId());
        stm.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()){
            this.setNome(rs.getString(1));
            this.setTelefone(rs.getString(2));
            this.setEmail(rs.getString(3));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } try {
        conn.rollback();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.println(e1.getStackTrace());
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                System.out.println(e1.getStackTrace());
            }
        } if (stm != null) {
            try {
                stm.close();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                System.out.println(e1.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E a classe do teste

```
@Test
void testCadastrar() {
if (c.cadastrar(b.conector())) // preciso de ajuda nessa linha, creio eu
System.out.println(“Sucesso”);
else
System.out.println(“falha”);

}
```

Comment: Você pode usar os Mocks para simular a persistência, e para verificar o resultado, terá de usar Assertions do JUnit pois ele valida o resultado final do seu método. Já se caso você decida testar o que foi persistido, antes de executar o teste, insira os registros no banco e teste se eles existem através do Assertions.

Comment: Um teste bem primitivo que você pode fazer com seu código da maneira que ele está seria executar seu método de cadastro, por exemplo, deixar ele inserir no banco e depois fazer uma busca para saber se ele inseriu. O grande problema dos seus métodos é que eles não retornam nada. O ideal é você retornar um booleano ou mesmo o objeto que você salvou ou carregou do banco. Desta forma você consegue testar se o retorno está nulo ou não, se é true ou false etc. Tente buscar material sobre testes unitários. A teoria é importante antes da prática, pra você saber o que testar.